# How to pass a widget variable to slot?

Tags: qt, events, variables, slot

I am a QT beginner and I am writing a GUI app that has two QPushButtons and two QTextEdits. When button 1 is clicked, I want only QTextEdit 1 to show something, when button 2 is clicked, I want only QTextEdit 2 to show something, below is my code, but it doesn't work because it seems that I cannot pass parameters to slot method....

```
class EventProcessor: public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

public slots:

    void PopulateEditTest(QTextEdit *textEdit, QString text)
    {
        textEdit->setText(text);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget *window = new QWidget;

    QTextEdit *result1 = new QTextEdit();
    QTextEdit *result2 = new QTextEdit();
    QPushButton *btFacility1 = new QPushButton("Facility 1");
    QPushButton *btFacility2 = new QPushButton("Facility 2");

    EventProcessor eventprocessor;


    QObject::connect(btFacility1, SIGNAL(clicked()), &eventprocessor, SLOT(PopulateEditTest
                    (result1, "textEdit1")));
    QObject::connect(btFacility2, SIGNAL(clicked()), result, SLOT(PopulateEditTest
                    (result2, "textEdit2")));

    ..........


    return app.exec();
}
```

I am wondering if there is a similar way to get this working? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that you cannot specify arguments to be passed to a slot when you call `QObject::connect`. All you are providing are function definitions, not function calls.

The simplest way to accomplish what you're trying to do would be to add a couple of slots to your event processor class:

```
class EventProcessor: public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

public slots:

    void PopulateEditTest(QTextEdit *textEdit, QString text) { ...  }
    void button1Clicked() {
        PopulateEditTest(dynamic_cast<QTextEdit*>(sender()), "textEdit1");
    }

    void button2Clicked() {
        PopulateEditTest(dynamic_cast<QTextEdit*>(sender()), "textEdit1");
    }
};

...

QObject::connect(btFacility1, SIGNAL(clicked()), &eventprocessor, SLOT(button1clicked()));
QObject::connect(btFacility2, SIGNAL(clicked()), &eventprocessor, SLOT(button2Clicked()));
```

There are various reasons why it is generally considered to be "evil" to use the `QObject::sender()` function in this manner, but it is the simplest way to accomplish what you're trying to do without rewriting all of your code, which would be pointless me of to do without knowing what your long term goals are.

Comment: Hi Chris. Thank you for your answer. I tried your code, but it still doesn't work. Does the sender in "dynamic_cast<QTextEdit*>(sender())" indicate the object that sends the signal? in this app, the button? btFacility1 or btFacility2 ?

Comment: Yes `sender()` returns a QObject* of the object that sent the signal

Comment: Thanks, Chris. That's very helpful...I can save lots of coding in this way.